# Deprecation Warning !! After running npm start on client side project. The following error has shown. It was working before the computer shut down

Tags: node.js, reactjs

> npm run start

> medicor-client@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

(node:13940) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_AFTER_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onAfterSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:13940) [DEP_WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_ON_BEFORE_SETUP_MIDDLEWARE] DeprecationWarning: 'onBeforeSetupMiddleware' option is deprecated. Please use the 'setupMiddlewares' option.
Starting the development server...
Compiled with warnings.

Warning
(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

(6:29521) autoprefixer: Replace color-adjust to print-color-adjust. The color-adjust shorthand is currently deprecated.

webpack compiled with 1 warning

Answer (score 0):

update bootstrap to the latest version using

npm install bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1

That should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

if you use npm add this in package-json folder;

```
"overrides": {
"autoprefixer": "10.4.5"
}
```

and go to the terminal;

```
npm install
```

then restart your project.

Comment: It worked for me though.

Answer (score 0):

Change This from your raect.js app
react.js app -nodemodules=>react-scripts=>config=>webpackDevServer.config.js

Change below code

onBeforeSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
// Keep `evalSourceMapMiddleware`
// middlewares before `redirectServedPath` otherwise will not have any effect
// This lets us fetch source contents from webpack for the error overlay
devServer.app.use(evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer));

```
  if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    // This registers user provided middleware for proxy reasons
    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app);
  }
},
onAfterSetupMiddleware(devServer) {
  // Redirect to `PUBLIC_URL` or `homepage` from `package.json` if url not match
  devServer.app.use(redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath));

  // This service worker file is effectively a 'no-op' that will reset any
  // previous service worker registered for the same host:port combination.
  // We do this in development to avoid hitting the production cache if
  // it used the same host and port.
  // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2272#issuecomment-302832432
  devServer.app.use(noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath));
},
```

With this

```
setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
  if (!devServer) {
    throw new Error('webpack-dev-server is not defined')
  }
  if (fs.existsSync(paths.proxySetup)) {
    require(paths.proxySetup)(devServer.app)
  }

  middlewares.push(
    evalSourceMapMiddleware(devServer),
    redirectServedPath(paths.publicUrlOrPath),
    noopServiceWorkerMiddleware(paths.publicUrlOrPath)
  )

  return middlewares;
},
```

Comment: Never change anything in "node_modules". The next npm i run overwrites the changes